# pipenv and pyinstaller not packaging dependencies

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pipenv

I'm fairly new to python I'm trying to create an executable of my python project that is run in pipenv. However, when I try and compile and run the code using pyinstaller it can't find any dependencies since they aren't installed globally. I don't want to install them globally, this is supposed to be a deployable build that shouldn't require any setup beyond just the exe.

Am I missing something? Is this even the right way to go?

I can run the project easily like so:

```
pipenv run python iot.py
```

It has a dependency:

```
from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient
```

And I try and compile the project like so:

```
pipenv run pyinstaller --onefile iot.py
```

It creates an executable that fails to find imported modules.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iot.py", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: No module named AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib
[48823] Failed to execute script iot
```

Am I just so off in my attempt or is there just a simple missing link?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 15):

This is because you installed pyinstaller globally.

Use `pipenv install -d pyinstaller` before packing.

Answer (score 5):

I found that pyinstaller won't package dependencies inside the pipenv.

If I install the dependencies globally I can ship the exe.

For now, I'll make a build machine that handles downloading dependencies and building the exe.

Answer (score 5):

You can tell pyinstaller to look in the virtual env created by pipenv when searching for the required modules.

```
$ pipenv --venv
path\to\.virtualenvs\project

$ pipenv run pyinstaller --paths path\to\.virtualenvs\project project.py
```